# Excessive padding causes accuracy decrease to NN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have trained a simple neural network model to make a binary classification and be able o separate real from fake news

```
#Create the class of the model
class FakeNewsDetectionModelV0(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self, input_size):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layer_1=nn.Linear(in_features=input_size, out_features=8)
        self.layer_2=nn.Linear(in_features=8, out_features=1) #takes the 5 features from the previous layer and outputs a single feature

     #define a forward() for the forward pass
     def forward(self, x, mask):
        
        # Apply the mask to ignore certain values
        if mask is not None:
            x = x * mask

        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        return x
```

I use CountVectorizer to turn text to list and subsequrently to tensor

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, lowercase=False)
vectorizer.fit(df['text'])

X=vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text']).toarray()
```

The problem is that because the dataset has more than 9000 entries the input size the model is trained on is really large (around 120000). So when i try to make predictions on single sentences, because the size is significally smaller i need to excessively pad the sentence to make it fit the model's input which greatly affect my model's accuracy.

```
from io import StringIO
from torch.nn.functional import pad
import string
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


try:
    #nltk.download('stopwords')
    nltk.download('punkt')
except:
    print("error in downloading stopwords")

def normalise_text (text):

  text = text.lower() # lowercase
  text = text.replace(r"\#","") # replaces hashtags
  text = text.replace(r"http\S+","URL")  # remove URL addresses
  text = text.replace(r"@","")
  text = text.replace(r"[^A-Za-z0-9()!?\'\`\"]", " ")
  text = text.replace("\s{2,}", " ")
  text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
  return text

def fake_news_detection(df, model, model_input_size):
    predictions = []
    max_words = 10000
    max_length = model_input_size

    model.eval()

    for prediction_data in df['text'][:4000]:
        prediction_data=normalise_text(prediction_data)

        #print([prediction_data])



        # Use CountVectorizer to transform text data to array
        vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, lowercase=False)
        prediction_data_array = vectorizer.fit_transform([prediction_data]).toarray()

        #tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
        #tokenizer.fit_on_texts([prediction_data])
        #sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([prediction_data])


        #prediction_data_array = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_length,value=-1.0)

        #print(prediction_data_array.shape)

        # Check the shape of the transformed data
        current_input_size = prediction_data_array.shape[1]


        prediction_data_tensor = torch.tensor(prediction_data_array, dtype=torch.float32)


        # If the shape doesn't match, resize it
        if current_input_size != model_input_size:

            print(current_input_size)
            padding = model_input_size - current_input_size
            prediction_data_tensor = pad(prediction_data_tensor, (0, padding), 'constant', value = 0)
            mask_tensor = torch.ones_like(prediction_data_tensor)
            mask_tensor[:, -padding:] = 0  # Set values in the padded region to 0
            #print(torch.unique(mask_tensor, return_counts=True))

            # Apply the mask to ignore certain values
            #prediction_data_tensor = prediction_data_tensor * mask_tensor



        # Assuming your model takes input_data as input
        with torch.inference_mode():
            prediction = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(model(prediction_data_tensor, mask_tensor))).squeeze()

        predictions.append(round(prediction.item()))

    print(f"our data tensor shape is  {prediction_data_tensor.shape}")

    predictions_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(predictions)

    return predictions_tensor
```

Does anyone know any workaround that allows me to fit the data to my model withou dropping its accuracy score ?

Tried : padding the vectors when making predictions on data that is of small size

Expected : Accurate predictions similar to the results i got in training/evaluation process

Got : Inaccurate predictions of really low accuracy (around 43%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a different featurizer for every step of your loop. This means you are giving a totally different feature vector to the model on every step.

You need to `fit` the `CountVectorizer` once on your train dataset, then use the same fitted `CountVectorizer` to transform all the data.

Comment: yes its all working properly now thanks a lot !